# Sonatype Nexus doesn't update single git submodule

Tags: docker, cache, git, jenkins, nexus

I have this setup:

-a git repository called MyRepo. This repo has 5 submodules (A,B,C,D,E)

-a Jenkins instance that auto-builds MyRepo. On post-build steps there's a simple script that executes:

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=$1
docker build -t server.com:5000/MyRepo:$branch .
docker push server.com:5000/MyRepo:$branch
```

-The server.com:5000 is the Nexus instance. Here all docker images are saved and can be pulled by docker-compose installations.

Now the problem is the submodule C (only this one) is never updated in the docker image. If I look the Jenkins workspace for MyRepo, the files are correctly updated.
The issue should be Nexus side, but I'm not sure where to look because it was configured by another person.
Is there any cache or something similiar? Are Nexus artifacts involved?

**EDIT**
My Dockerfile: (I leave the commented out rows, maybe the other person left me with something useful there)

```
FROM node:8-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/webapp
COPY package.json ./
#COPY Gruntfile.js ./
COPY start_http_server.sh ./
#COPY bower.json ./
#COPY .bowerrc ./
#RUN yarn
COPY site ./site #this folder includes the git sumbodules files
COPY node_modules ./node_modules
#RUN ./node_modules/.bin/bower install
#RUN ./node_modules/.bin/grunt

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./start_http_server.sh"]
```

Comment: I'd be pretty sure that Nexus isn't involved at all, since the issue arrises in the `docker build`-step. Check/post your Dockerfile

Comment: @ppuschmann I edited the question.

Comment: is there some file ".dockerignore"? Please check this vs. your "COPY site ./site"

Comment: @ppuschmann yes but it just includes 2 dirs and a file: components, target, Gruntfile.js .